# Vector Fields and Line Fields on Manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, vector-bundles, vector-fields, tangent-spaces

Let $M$ be a manifold of dimension $m$ and $p\in M$, then $T_p(M)$, the tangent space of $M$ at the point $p$, is also of dimension $m$.

A vector field $X$ on $M$ is a map that associates to each point $p\in M$ a vector $X(p)$ of $T_p(M)$, so $X(p)$ has $m$ coordinates.

A line field $P$ on $M$ is a map that associates to each point $p\in M$ a vector subspace of dimension one $P(p)$ of $T_p(M)$, so $\dim(P(p))=1$.

It is said, as an example, if $X$ is a non-singular vector field on $M$, we can define a line field $P$ on by letting $$P(p)= \mathbb{R} . X(p)$$

How could this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All multiples of vector $X(p)$ gives you that subspace of $T_p(M)$.

Comment: what is the dimension of the induced subspace?

Comment: one, because $P(p)$ is generated by only one vector which is $X(p)$